# if/else vs ternary operator

Tags: if-statement, operators, ternary-operator, conditional-operator, micro-optimization

Considering the evaluation time, are following two equivalent?

```
if(condition1)
{
    //code1
}
else
{
    //code2
}
```

`condition1 ? code1 : code2`

Or they are just syntactically different?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference is that the latter station can be used to **return a value** based on a condition.

For example, if you have a following statement:

```
if (SomeCondition())
{
    text = "Yes";
}
else
{
    text = "No";
}
```

Using a ternary operator, you will write:

```
text = SomeCondition() ? "Yes" : "No";
```

Note how the first example *executes a statement* based on a condition, while the second one *returns a value* based on a condition.

Answer (score 4):

Well ... In the former case, you can have any amount or type (expression vs statement) of code in place of `code1` and `code2`. In the latter case, they must be valid expressions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes & Yes.

Only profit is to save lines of code.

Comment: Not the only one. The second variant can be used to bind a reference to two different object depending on condition, the first one can't be used for that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these are two different syntactical forms and will work identically and most likey identical code will be emitted by the compiler.