# Meaning of the "int N = a == b ? a : a + b == 10 ? a + b : 0;"

Tags: c, conditional-statements

```
int a = 5, b = 7;
int N = a == b ? a : a + b == 10 ? a + b : 0;
```

What is the meaning of the following code?
Update: Mainly i want to know for which cause I can use it and how it works ?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: You may find info on [the **ternary operator**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) helpful. Also discussed compared to if-else [on **this very site**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659992/if-else-vs-ternary-operator).

Comment: If this helps, this is what it would look like if it used if statements http://pastebin.com/raw/LCvjaYFw

Comment: That means that whoever wrote the code needs to be made to maintain it forever (or they should be taken out, shot, hung, drawn, quartered and then made to fix the code so it is vaguely maintainable).  It's an abomination, and only a sadistic tutor would write code like that.

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks, I got the answer :))

Answer (score 0):

With implicit parenthesis, this expression is equivalent to:

```
int N = (a == b) ? a : ((a + b) == 10) ?  (a + b) : 0;
```

This assigns to `N`:

1. The value of `a`, if `a` and `b` are equal.  If not...
2. The value of `a + b`, if `a + b` is 10 (i.e. `N` is assigned 10).  If not...
3. The value `0`.

I've most often seen this construct used when calculating the number of days in February for a given year.

```
int febDays = (year % 4 != 0) ? 28 : 
                (year % 100 != 0) ? 29 : 
                  (year % 400 != 0) ? 28 : 29;
```